# Use hindi or kannada language for microsoft speech sdk

Tags: sdk, microsoft-speech-api

Is there any language packs available in Hindi or Kannada for Microsoft Speech SDK. Hindi and Kannada are languages spoken in India.

Answer (score 0):

The list of supported languages for version 11 is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378476.aspx) and the closest to what you ask is the [English - Indian runtime language](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/0/D/40D6347A-AFA5-417D-A9BB-173D937BEED4/MSSpeech_SR_en-IN_TELE.msi). Download it and check if it has what you need.